# Merge N number of objects and get intersection type with all properties

Tags: typescript

Consider these three objects:

```
const obj = {
    name: 'bob',
};

const obj2 = {
    foo: 'bar',
};

const obj3 = {
    fizz: 'buzz',
};
```

I've written a simple merge function that merges these three objects into one:

```
// suboptimal solution. Only takes in 3 params
const merge = <A extends Record<string, unknown>, B extends Record<string, unknown>, C extends Record<string, unknown>>(...rest: [A, B, C]) => {
    return rest.reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, ...curr }), {}) as A & B & C;
};

// Totally works. IDE TypeScript support autocomplete works and the return type is exactly as
// expected. test1 type has properties of "foo", "name", and "fizz"
const test1 = merge(obj, obj2, obj3);
```

There are two problems with this:

1. It only supports 3 objects at the moment. I want to support N number of objects.
2. The generic is freaking huge

The return type of this function (observable by hovering over `test1`) is an intersection of all the inferred types of the 3 objects passed in. Beautiful - exactly what I'm looking for, but the solution is still suboptimal.

I've tried doing this:

```
// Attempting to take in N number of objects instead of just supporting 3
const merge2 = <T extends Record<string, unknown>[]>(...rest: T) => {
    // Merging them all
    return rest.reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, ...curr }), {});
};

// Function obviously works, but test2 type is just "Record<string, unknown>". TypeScript doesn't seem to
// know that test2 has "name", "foo", and "fizz" properties
const test2 = merge2(obj, obj2, obj3)
```

The function of course is the same, but instead I'm trying to accept an arbitrary number of objects. The problem is that the return type the function is always `Record<string, unknown>`, so the type inferences for the 3 (or more) objects passed in is totally lost. Therefore, you can't do `test2.f` and get autocomplete for `foo`.

How can I avoid losing the object types? And how can I created an intersection between N number of types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses the `UnionToIntersection` type from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/8613630).

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

const merge = <
  T extends any[]
>(...rest: T): UnionToIntersection<T[number]> => {    
    return rest.reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, ...curr }), {});
};
```

I used the generic type `T` to store all the types passed as `args` in an array. Using `T[number]` we can get a union of all elements in the array `T`. With the `UnionToIntersection` type, we convert this union to an intersection which will be the return type of the function.

Let's see if it works:

```
const test = merge(obj, obj2, obj3)
// const test: {
//     name: string;
// } & {
//     foo: string;
// } & {
//     fizz: string;
// }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDHMwEMBbAUwC4YByeBCgGkwF8BuTTUSWBRAJlQ21wAzECHJV8AJzqMWbcNDhIAzHyy4YggJYAvbWPgBXXdOasoATwAOxGAFUwm8ABUQASTBRiEiMWBRHYAA8tgB8fAIAFLYwxAAenmAAJhAw+GDmMAD8MBEA1uS2AJQoIQBuIJqJMORgxKVehTHxxEkpEXnkmmCCXjCuxWUViY3ZrtV4dV6s7AokEgDmNmiBAk5NCcmp6QDaALqYIREAdCcSxNDkToUFDs5uHl4+fgGBTttgBoTwXrthJRjqAQ4M5QAwSMAwM7QI5nRIGYDEdr4YDAWgwYBgiSNf4RdAwE5HZGo-EnDESCQwBiFNHoKksUzTeSwTwKNBzRYRLhorjcbnKQqYAD0gvRTJgLKg5CwwvUeCIZBg0AkXXmLBlDBgADJ+DL1MJRIqoMqwKqhSKNdrpSK9To9Ibjab1UA)